# A woman I would like to marry is married to another man; what am I to do and how can she get a divorce?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I'm in love with a woman and she also loves me a lot. But she is married. Her husband gives her rights. He is always making her sad and he is having affairs with other women which is zina.

She wants talaq (divorce) but he is not allowing it. He just scold or beat her if she asks.

He is not good person.  I also want to marry her.  In this situation, what am I to do?  How can she get divorced?

Comment: I edited your Question but one sentence is unclear does her husband give her rights or not. Because the way you wrote this sentence is suggesting he gives her rights. But this seems contradictory to context of your Question!

Comment: may be you're the reason that "He just scold or beat her if she asks." so if you want her to live a good life, perhaps you should leave her and stop thinking about her.

Answer (score 1):

Wa'alailumussalam warahmatullahi wabarakatuh, dear brother.

> I'm in love with a woman and she also loves me a lot. But she is married. Her husband gives her rights.

I would like to remind you to be careful brother since having intimate relationship with someone else's wife is haram and prohibited in Islam. **Be careful with satan trickery.**

> He is always making her sad and he is having affairs with other women
>   which is zina.

You can help her by making sure it is a valid accusation. It is a serious accusation towards any muslim. Make sure that you are not easily come into conclusion without any proof.

> how can she get divorced?

Divorcing married couple is a sin. All you can do as a third person is helping her case reported to reputable people for help. She can then ask a judge opinion to divorce her marriage.

You can ask her for marriage once she is no longer someone's wife (and finished her i'ddah).

Comment: "Divorcing married couple is a sin." Did you mean "coming between a husband and a wife is a sin"? Divorce itself may be disliked, but it is halal.

Comment: the idea of divorce must come from the couple itself. If someone else is trying to break the bond (by having an affair or manipulation or whatever the means may be), then it is one of the biggest of all sins.

Answer (score -1):

1. Having talaq is her right, if she feels uncomfortable with that guy, she has all the rights to leave him. Ask her to file a case against him and also meet local reputable people for help. Seek police protection if necessary
2. loving fellow humans is a good thing. However if this love is different from other humans, then you might consider the role of hormones in this too.

However do help her. Tell her parents. Your parents and others about it, to help her

Comment: "Having talaq is her right" References? The woman only has a right to seek divorce in quite restricted cases.

Comment: @G.Bach that's exactly what I said too, it's her "right" (obviously under various conditions - due to which she don't want to live with that man :) )

Comment: I've never seen "she's uncomfortable with the guy" as one of the cases in which a woman can demand to be divorced, that's why I asked for references.

Comment: @G.Bach i'm sure you never saw english words in any hadith or ayat too :) they were in arabic anyway :) so lets not get too rigid just to justify our cultures